# What's this number in my Reputation tab?

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-history

The `<span>` it's in has class `bounty-indicator-tab`, and I don't see any meaning to the number `9` in tab's content. Bug?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

It means that you've earned 9 reputation points since you last looked at the page.

The **style** is called `bounty-indicator-tab` because the team have given the number the same look and feel as the number of featured questions on the site.

Comment: That's kind of an awkward number to show. Today I earned rep in increments of 10 (except for a +2), so I still don't see how 9 could possibly be right.

Comment: @Matt - 1 up vote received by you - 1 down vote given by you = net 9 points. This looks like only one vote so you must have down-voted earlier in the day and hit the rep cap.

Comment: I'm nowhere near rep cap for today, but I did cast a downvote on an answer which was then deleted. Even though I triggered a rep recalc before grabbing that screenshot, that's probably the answer.

Comment: @Matt - I did take a look at your profile after posting that comment and didn't see a -1 and was going to add something about caching of values (honest)